# Set and Set Operations in Javascript

Tags: javascript, collections, set

I'm looking for Set and Set operations in Javascript for intersection, union and difference instead of having to write them manually. Here's equivalent Java code:

```
    Set<Integer> toMerged = new HashSet<Integer>(to);
    toMerged.addAll(memory);

    Set<Integer> toFiltered = new HashSet<Integer>(toMerged);
    Set<Integer> memoryFiltered = new HashSet<Integer>(toMerged);

    toFiltered.retainAll(lookupSet);
    memoryFiltered.removeAll(lookupSet);
```

As seen in code above, I'm looking for for equivalent addAll, retainAll and removeAll methods in a Set implementation in Javascript. Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Possible duplicate of of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342749/is-there-a-library-for-a-set-data-type-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the specified intersection, union, and difference operations are unavailable in the current Javascript Set implementation.
However, on the [MDN page for the Set class,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) you can find possible implementations.

```
function union(setA, setB) {
  const _union = new Set(setA);
  for (const elem of setB) {
    _union.add(elem);
  }
  return _union;
}
function intersection(setA, setB) {
  const _intersection = new Set();
  for (const elem of setB) {
    if (setA.has(elem)) {
      _intersection.add(elem);
    }
  }
  return _intersection;
}
function difference(setA, setB) {
  const _difference = new Set(setA);
  for (const elem of setB) {
    _difference.delete(elem);
  }
  return _difference;
}
```